# how to save the changes made in SQL using Python?

Tags: python, mysql, syntax-error

I wrote a code to enter data in SQL using python. Everything goes fine but when the program is closed, all the data entered is lost. Consider this code.

```
os.system('cls')
nme = input("enter your name: ")
usid = input("enter your userID: ")
pasd = getpass.getpass("please enter a pin in digits, characters are not supported: ")
entry = """insert into users (name, ID, pin) values(%s, %s, %s)"""
data = (nme, usid, pasd)
curs.execute(entry, data)
curs.commit()
```

I found on web that `curs.commit()` saves the changes made but it is showing an error.
[this is what the compiler shows the error!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx0DR.png)

Comment: cursor is for running queries. Please commit on connection var which provided cursor.

Comment: @mangupt yep i found!! thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cursor got from the connection object is only for running queries.
If you need to Commit/Rollback on failure please do this on Connection object itself.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save your changes in your databases. You have to write`.commit()` with your database. There is a small example of saving changes in mysql database using python.

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="your_database"
)
mycurs = mydb.cursor()
mycurs.execute("INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')")
mydb.commit()    #".commit()" is with database variable not with cursor
```

May be it helps you